# Read the first number in a line, move on to next line without reading the rest of the line until end of file

Tags: java

I am reading from a txt file. It has stuff in it like...

```
2 // Two
3
40 // oh look, forty
```

Currently the output looks like this...

```
2
//
Two
3
40
//
oh
look,
forty
```

I don't want that. I just want the integers, so the output should be...

```
2
3
40
```

I want to read just the integer at the beginning of the line, ignore the rest of the line then move to the next line. I will keep doing this until I reach the end of the file. Ultimately all these integers will go into an array.

```
    try {
        File program = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(program);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.next();
            System.out.println(data);
            
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried BufferedReader but I think it can't do what I want it to do, so I went with a Scanner. If it matters here is my attempt with that.

```
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: read the whole line, then use regex to extract the numbers.

Comment: If all your lines have that specific format (integer, then space....) you can split[0] your line to get the first integer

Comment: The following regex could be used to see if the line starts with an integer `^\d+`

Comment: `String data = myReader.nextLine().replaceAll("(^\\d+).*", "$1");` should do it

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want only the first number found in a line of text,  I'll use [Scanner.nextInt](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/).

```
try {
    File program = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner myReader = new Scanner(program);
    while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        Integer data = myReader.nextInt();
        myReader.nextLine(); // avoid reading 7 as nextInt. eg. "5 // seven 7"
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    myReader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not Found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```